# Chromecast drm support for ios

Tags: ios, chromecast, drm

There is an example in chromecast documentation

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#streamdrm

which mentions to set the customData for receiver with.

```
host.licenseCustomData = customData;
```

On iOS sender app

we have

```
 GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation = [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:[url absoluteString]
                                                                                streamType:streamType
                                                                               contentType:mimeType
                                                                                  metadata:metadata
                                                                            streamDuration:0
                                                                                customData:customData];
```

So I can pass that customData here in the media Information.

The other way to do it is, we pass the intial url of stream to receiver and then receiver the extracts the information of customData from url inside the receiver.

Which is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: I think the best way is to check if which one of the two ways benefits you the most, or which one work on you. But if you considered the documentation, then go with the host.licenseCustomData = customData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, whichever works for your case and is easier for you can be used. One thing to keep in mind is whether it makes any difference when multiple devices are connected to the same receiver; one approach may make it easier for multi-sender case than the other one.